# Reverse of bytes to Hex program to convert Hex to bytes

Tags: java, python, hex, byte

I am trying to write the reverse of the below program to get the bytes from the HEX value that i have. Finding it hard to do it. Any help?

```
private static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    char[] hexChars = new char [bytes.length *2];

    for (int i=0; i< bytes.length; i++) {
        int v = bytes[i] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[i*2] = HEX_ARRAY[v >>>4];
        hexChars[i*2 + 1] = HEX_ARRAY[v & 0x0F];

    }
    return new String(hexChars);
}
```

Consider HEX_ARRAY as char[] HEX_ARRAY = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();

I would prefer to do this python but even Java should be ok

Comment: so what is stopping you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you want help, you will need to post what you have tried so far, and explain why it isn't working. See [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Rather than rolling your own hex/string/byte converter, I strongly recommend using one of the many many libraries out there already built for this purpose. Saves a lot of headaches.

Comment: I just figured out that python has a library binascci and i can use the below code: `import binascii
binascii.hexlify('ax')`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help everyone. I resolved this by using

```
import binascii
```

`binascii.hexlify('data')`

For the JAVA code I found the answer here:
https://github.com/EverythingMe/inbloom/blob/master/java/src/main/java/me/everything/inbloom/BinAscii.java